# WPF Multiple DataTriggers bound to same source

Tags: wpf, storyboard, datatrigger

I finally tracked down my storyboard datatrigger issue. The issue appears to occur because I have 2 DataTriggers bound to the same viewmodel property:

```
    <Grid Panel.ZIndex="95" Height="234" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,85,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Background="#FF454540" Opacity="1">
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SearchMenuState}" Value="{x:Static local:SideMenuState.Shown}">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="69,85,0,0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SearchMenuState}" Value="{x:Static local:SideMenuState.Hidden}">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="0,85,0,0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

When I comment out the second DataTrigger, the first one works. Why is that, and how can I correct it so that both work?

Comment: Isn't DataTrigger.EnterActions a collection type? Can't you just put both actions in that collection? Ah I see you have two different triggers, I'm sure this works for me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [use data trigger control the storyboard, but only trigger one time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410464/use-data-trigger-control-the-storyboard-but-only-trigger-one-time)

Comment: Found the answer. See link above