# wpf databinding datatrigger to animate a rectangle

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatrigger

I am using MVVM so I need to bind a rectangle shape a property which will eventually animate it.
I've found few [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410464/use-data-trigger-control-the-storyboard-but-only-trigger-one-time) and tried to replicate their approach but the storybroad doesnt kick in
I am including my source code

```
<Rectangle x:Name="RectangleCompleted" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="440,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Stroke="#FF0BB3AE" StrokeThickness="5"           RadiusX="8" RadiusY="7" >   

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Animation}" Value="ON" Comparison="Equal">
      <ei:ControlStoryboardAction
      Storyboard="{StaticResource MyAnimation}" ControlStoryboardOption="Play"/>
   </ei:DataTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

<Rectangle.Effect>
   <DropShadowEffect RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="3" Color="#FFD2D6D8"/>
</Rectangle.Effect>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
       <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFE7F4F6"/>
   </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>

<Window.Resources>        
   <Storyboard x:Key="MyAnimation">
      <DoubleAnimation
       Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleCompleted"
       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
       From="0"
       To="1"
       RepeatBehavior="Forever"
       AutoReverse="True"/>
  </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your `Animation` property a `bool` or `string`? If it's a bool you need the value in your trigger check for True or False. If it's a string, then you should be fine with what you got. Provided your implementation of INPC and the `Animation` property is right this should work fine.

I've put together an example with the code you've posted and you should see it work fine. [Download Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvekg7z2qvs474a/MVVMAnimateRect.rar)

I've made two small change. I've added a Button to toggle the animation to either start or stop and put the entire thing in a `StackPanel`. Secondly I made the `Animation` property a bool so just had the Triggers to check for "True" or "False" than the "ON" value you were checking for.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <Rectangle x:Name="RectangleCompleted"
              Width="100"
              Height="50"
              RadiusX="8"
              RadiusY="7"
              Stroke="#FF0BB3AE"
              StrokeThickness="5">
    <Rectangle.Resources>
      <Storyboard x:Key="MyAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimation AutoReverse="True"
                          From="0"
                          RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                          Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleCompleted"
                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                          To="1" />
      </Storyboard>
    </Rectangle.Resources>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Animation}"
                      Comparison="Equal"
                      Value="True">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Play"
                                    Storyboard="{StaticResource MyAnimation}" />
      </ei:DataTrigger>
      <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Animation}"
                      Comparison="Equal"
                      Value="False">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Stop"
                                    Storyboard="{StaticResource MyAnimation}" />
      </ei:DataTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Rectangle.Effect>
      <DropShadowEffect RenderingBias="Quality"
                        ShadowDepth="3"
                        Color="#FFD2D6D8" />
    </Rectangle.Effect>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFE7F4F6" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>
  <Button Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}"
          Content="Toggle Animation" />
</StackPanel>
```

and all `ToggleCommand` does is:

```
ToggleCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Animation = !Animation);
```

**Update:**

If you just want to trigger your animation when the window loads, all you need is:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Storyboard x:Key="MyAnimation">
    <DoubleAnimation AutoReverse="True"
                      From="0"
                      RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                      Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleCompleted"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                      To="1" />
  </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyAnimation}" />
  </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks Viv, its good. Can I do it without using command?
I want to animate on window load

Comment: @ssq the command in this example has nothing to do with your original question. So yeh you can remove it and just have one trigger to start the animation. It was something I added to show how to stop the animation. Command's are fundamental parts for MVVM. Bindings and Commands are what helps decouple the View from the VM

Comment: I understand that, but in my case (and in your example) I cant trigger the animation i.e initialize Animation=true (doesnt work)
so essentially my question is to trigger the animation on Window load via ViewModel

Comment: @ssq where in your question do you mention Window loaded triggering your animation? and what does the VM have to do with triggering this for a loaded event of a view? Am sorry but you've just lost me. If you want your animation to trigger when the window is loaded, simply use an event trigger for the window loaded event and start your storyboard.

Comment: I think thats what I meant when I said the storyboard doesnt kick in?
As per my understanding change in the binded  Animation value (Binding Path=Animation) should start the animation?

Comment: well in the example I attached changing the Bound value does trigger the animation. So not sure what you meant with "but in my case (and in your example) I cant trigger the animation i.e initialize Animation=true (doesnt work)"

Comment: sorry if this doesn't make sense, I just want to trigger the animation without use of a button
I'll look into EventTrigger as you suggested

Comment: @ssq Np. If all you want is to run the animation when the Window Loads, then see the update I just added to the bottom of my answer. that's all you should need to use `EventTrigger` and start the `StoryBoard`