# Start Storyboard with a DataTrigger

Tags: xaml, storyboard, datatrigger

I want to start a Storyboard with a Datatrigger. Now I have a solution with a Eventtrigger that works for me. This is my code:

```
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="test" ImageSource="Tulips.jpg"></ImageBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>      
    <Rectangle.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ImageSource)" 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="test">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="Tulips.jpg" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="Chrysanthemum.jpg" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```

Now I want to start the storyboard with a data trigger if a variable in Code Behind File is set to a specific value. How can I do this?

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410464/use-data-trigger-control-the-storyboard-but-only-trigger-one-time

Comment: this example doesn't work. Interaction, DataTrigger, ControlStoryBoardAction, ... are not in the namespace

Comment: You can get the dll here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk/

This also includes an Interactivity .dll for Windows Store apps.

Comment: i have added the dll from the nuget source. in the linked sample i get no errort for this source xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"  but i get an error that the components are not in the namespace for this source: xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" Is there another dll I needed?